# how does kernel code access memory at the assembly level

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mmu

Many articles have stated that，in 32-bit Linux when kernel code accesses memory, the MMU converts linear addresses above 3G to physical addresses, `physical addr = logical addr - 0xC0000000`.

So how does kernel code access memory at the assembly level? For example, the kernel has a global variable called `foo`, which at the C level is `foo=123`. So what is it at the assembly level?

Is it `movl $123, foo(%0xC0000000)`? Am I think the address is `ds + 0xC0000000 + foo`, which translates to the physical address being `foo` by MMU ?

Comment: You have to specify architecture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension is specific for x86

Comment: The code will access the variable at its virtual address. The MMU will translate that to the physical address.

Comment: Why "assembly"? C and assembly for such things are very similar. Assembly doesn't have more information, and still it works with virtual addresses. Do you want physical address? Just create a segment which map all physical memory linearly. *Many articles* are wrong or obsolete. Link to what you think it is the best one, so we can comment.